# Please bring back the bluish syntax colouring

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I always thought that beige syntax colouring was a Meta thing because Meta was a greyed out version of SO.

Now the beige keywords are used on SO as well, making it look... somehow wrong.

Would it be possible to bring back the default VS bluish keywords, with different shades of blue for different languages, as it used to be?

Comment: That took surprisingly long.

Comment: I guess all the bluish went onto some buttons.

Comment: I disagree with this. The easy beige colours look more professional and fit the reduced, simplified fonts and design that's taken over.

Comment: Even when Visual Studio went beige, it kept coloured syntax highlighting.

Comment: For the R language syntax highlighting, keywords now have almost the same color as strings and numbers. This is a regression.

Comment: I was actually going to raise this earlier, along with the fact that HTML/markup tags are now green, *ugh*

Comment: I can only second that. Why on earth is XML now highlighted in _green_? Seems like an utterly pointless change. Can we have the original colors back? I think it was something like maroon.

Comment: @mattytommo: I get the hunch that they made HTML green to match JSFiddle (ironically, given the introduction of Stack Snippets). Not that I agree with the change of course...

Comment: [Beige is for alerts...](http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/Beige+alert_81608e_5336018.jpg)