# New syntax highlighting just got me color blind

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, syntax-highlighting

#### Stack Overflow design update

So, as you already know, Stack Overflow (and its related Meta subdomain) recently got updated with this brand new style, which, in my opinion, is really pure and enjoyable.

However, answering and reading questions, **I got really annoyed by the new syntax-highlight colors**: they all just became different shades of brown. Leaving out the syntax-highlight for `<markup tags>` and properties, which actually made them more visible (but still arguably cheerful),

[image: HTML]

the new syntax highlight for programming languages just became impossible to realize. I spend most of the time on the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) tags, which are an example of this.

#### Incomprehensible syntax-highlighting

I'm not saying that the old syntax-highlight must be brought back, but just that the new one became incomprehensible, and **I literally feel color blind looking at any snippet** right now. Take a look at these examples, one from [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and one from [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), and you'll see:

[image: Python]

[image: JavaScript]

**Don't you also feel a bit lost looking at that code?** I mean: **syntax-highlight was invented to make it easier to read code**: keywords with one color, strings wrapped inside quotes in another one, numbers in a third one, and so on...

The only thing I can see now is a bunch of grey lines with some shade of brown.
Really, just take a look inside it:

- Keywords are `#8a4a0b` (light brown)
- Numbers are `#953838` (little bit darker brown)
- Strings are `#800000` (brown tending to red)

The only things that I've seen in a different color are the objects (variables starting with capital letters), which are `#2b91af` (light blue) and some mathematical symbols, which are `#145680` (just a bit darker). All the rest basically became brown, and (maybe is a matter of habit) **I'm pretty confused by this change**. Strings were used to be in some shade of red, and numbers in a similar shade; keywords in dark blue, and so on. **That was a clear syntax-highlight**: seeing some red text would automatically mean that there was a string, as long as seeing some blue text would automatically mean there was some private word.

#### So, my final questions are:

Is there a chance to get an update for the new syntax-highlight style? Something more comprehensible and readable? Or will I have to personally write some custom CSS and add them to my [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=it) extension?

Comment: I [agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283730/1412059). This is really impairing readability of code.

Comment: An earlier question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283679/11683 (not voting to close as duplicate because of the nice explanation in this question)

Comment: @GSerg thanks, that question is really poorly worded IMHO.

Comment: Why in the world people use JPEGs for storing screenshots? Especially when reporting something about design flaws...

Comment: @TLama this is not some kind of design problem where you have to look at the single pixel, JPEG is more than enough in this case: text is perfectly readable, the colors render ok, and the size is reasonable. Plus anyone looking for more detailed examples can go to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) by their own and see any snippet on any tag.

Comment: @Marco, more than enough? Text is perfectly readable?! Colors render ok?! JPEG totally sucks here, don't you see that?

Comment: @TLama okay, I've got to admit it: those image are not that good... what can I say, I know other formats are way better, just edit my post and replace them with PNGs, if you want. [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27981903/3889449), [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25095250/3889449)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

TL;DR - **This was not an intended change**. A build is being deployed now that corrects it.

This is the default prettify theme but not the one Stack Overflow has used for...well, pretty much always. What happened here was that we *completely* rewrote the LESS that generates the Stack Overflow CSS. Part of the re-styling of Stack Overflow (that began with some other SE sites and pt.SO) is to unify our LESS base files and variables making creating new sites and maintenance much easier all around. Another aspect of this change is moving to SVG graphics and generally enabling high-DPI friendly styling across our network.

The prettify overrides didn't make it in correctly, which is what has just been fixed and deployed.

Comment: So are you bringing the old theme back, or just another version?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the old prettify colors should be back to exactly what they were now - we didn't intend or want to change them at all.

Comment: Oh thank goodness, good.

Comment: Might just be me, but didn't the font size for for code blocks use to be the same as the post text? Or is it that the code block font size is what it was, it's just the post font is different / larger? Either way - it still doesn't look *quite right*

Comment: @JonClements I've just posted a question about that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283971

Comment: **If it ain't broke, don't fix it.**

Comment: @Vector If you don't fix it, the break will be more severe when it does come. :P

Comment: @JeremyBanks - All too true. Points for that one. :) I actually spend a lot of time fixing things that aren't broken... yet....

Comment: @NickCraver BTW, do y'all still use LESS? Or have you switched to Sass (or, dare I ask, writing actual CSS [where possible]) since 2015?

Answer (score 23):

I completely agree.

I'm normally hanging about doing something or other with the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag and I've certainly noticed the difference. Maybe we're just spoilt by highlighting - but to me, this is *almost pointless* highlighting... I made a post about how the android app. was doing [different highlighting than the main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244600/syntax-highlighting-in-app-differs-from-normal-web-view) a while back and I'd certainly take that over the current state.

I'm not saying some things in the new design aren't good - but this really is something that should be reverted/or at the very least changed imho.

Answer (score -14):

I don't feel lost at all with the last examples. I think the first one looks like clown makeup, it's horrible to read. I much prefer the muted tones the later two examples.

I think the take-away is this is purely subjective.