# If it ain't broke

Tags: discussion, design

I know, I'm going to be another one complaining about it, but...

In my personal opinion, the redesign is a *foolish* move. My first thoughts on seeing it were:

> What is this? There's something wrong with the site! I don't like change!

And that's just it. I feel the update was change for the sake of change. I don't see anything that was improved - on the contrary, many things have been made worse. I wouldn't mind the change if it all worked, but as it stands...

With all due respect, could you please change it back until you've tested it properly? Maybe roll out a beta version for volunteers to try out and give it some thorough road-testing before forcing it on everyone? Maybe?

Comment: Fun fact: I'm actually working on a redesign of a major feature on my own site. Today I released a demo version for people to experiment with in different browsers and provide feedback on. It works brilliantly, and makes the community feel more involved in the site they are a community on.

Comment: It *was* tested.  The testing was done here on meta.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Apparently, not enough, considering the problem reports and issues I've seen raised today alone.

Comment: Why post a meta question if all you're going to say is "I don't like it" without any concrete feedback?

Comment: I'd argue that you can only do so much testing on Meta, which is a very, very small subset of the actual main site's usage.  You're going to run into more edge cases on Stack Overflow because of more prevalent usage of those cases.

Comment: @Makoto: That makes an excellent case for closed beta testing on the main site.

Comment: More constructively, I'd love to hear what the designer(s) felt was improved/fixed in the new design (more specifically than ["typographical consistency, white spacing and layout"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update), with some examples of what was broken/suboptimal), to demonstrate it isn't a new design for the sake of a new design.

Comment: @Pokechu22: And at least some of the feedback was ignored: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283617/vote-count-on-posts-in-the-flag-history-looks-broken#comment143089_283617 , though some things were indeed fixed.

Comment: One thing that works much *better* under the new design is nested quotes. Before it was very difficult to see where this was happening, but now it is quite clear.

Comment: Everything just... blends together too much.  Nothing is differentiated.

Comment: @Doorknob: There's enough [concrete feedback out there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug+design)…

Comment: @Bergi:  There's [definitely a decent amount of concrete feedback](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug+design+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro), but not nearly as much as you're insinuating.

Comment: +1 to this, the new design is far too bright, and more than a little headache-inducing

Comment: I can't see why this question's been voted to be closed. If @NiettheDarkAbsol didn't post it, I would have or somebody else. I for one do not like the fact that it's a **complete whitewash** and the question titles are **very hard to read**. This is a perfectly valid question and Stack should take this seriously and take comments into consideration. If this is something to reduce traffic and the amount of questions posted/answered, then they're doing a good job of it.

Comment: Plus, not to mention about the horizontal scrolling. We're in 2015, not 1995. Didn't they ever think of using responsive design? Also, Stack's new design looks too much like Meta. They should have their own identity.

Answer (score 29):

> I feel the update was change for the sake of change.

It wasn't. We're perpetually strapped for designer time; wasting it on superfluous changes is not something we can afford.

And that's a big reason why this redesign was necessary... There haven't been any major rework done to the SO design since the first year of its life. Additions for new features, tweaks here and there for consistency, but the core was getting *pretty long in the tooth* - and that's a big problem when you're trying to maintain designs for > 100 sites: eventually, there's so much metaphorical duct tape and bailing twine holding everything together that even trivial changes or fixes are likely to break something, to say nothing of the sheer *pain* involved in trying to make changes or additions consistent across all sites.

Jin & Co. did their best for years to keep it all together, but if you poke around a bit you'll find countless unfixed design bugs - here and on other sites - and a backlog of new work stretching out to the horizon. **Designs accumulate technical debt too, and it was time to pay the piper.**

Yeah, there's gonna be some pain. Some things changed intentionally for consistency (internal consistency or consistency with other sites), for ease of maintenance or simply to provide a solid foundation for future enhancements. Others changed... unintentionally. We'll need to fix those, and both dev and design teams are working hard on that - big thanks to everyone here carefully reporting bugs, and *especially* the folks who hammered on the beta design that's been live here on meta for several months.

But for all the short-term pain, the value going forward is huge: we can roll out new designs and fix bugs without just adding to the patchwork of site- or page-specific hacks and work-arounds, paying down debt and making better use of the small dedicated team of designers we're building here.

Comment: Which items are for consistency - if fonts then there is a bug issue

Comment: Roughly translated: _We don't care what you all think, we've changed it and it's here to stay._

Comment: I like it.  And I think you and the SO team are doing a great job.  You can't please everyone

Comment: I understand that "metaphorical duct tape" is awkward but many of the changes are seemingly pointless. Why does the new design change the colors of syntax highlighting for many languages? I'd really appreciate if someone would address this.

Comment: *"if you poke around a bit you'll find countless unfixed design bugs"* ... So just fix the bugs ...? Refactor the stuff? Nothing in your post makes a convincing argument why a *redesign* was required, which is *not* the same thing as a *refactor* of the CSS/HTML/JS/whatever ...

Comment: I agree with @Carpetsmoker. I'm extremely sympathetic to the technical debt argument, and can see *some* changes arising from that, as you make elements more consistent. But it's important to try to minimize those changes, and to ensure that what changes do occur are as much an improvement as possible, and I don't see evidence of either one here. I can't imagine how the enormous change in contrast on the main SO page arose by accident during the removal of technical debt.

Comment: "enormous change in contrast"? That's pure hyperbole, @ChrisHayes. But I'm not going to try to refute it. Here's the Wayback Machine: [before](https://web.archive.org/web/20150115190927/http://stackoverflow.com/), [after](https://web.archive.org/web/20150116052942/http://stackoverflow.com/) - and just for the hell of it, [end of 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20101229025739/http://stackoverflow.com/). You want to debate the relative merits of **bold text?** Then do that - I'll probably agree with you. But I got no time for chicken little.

Comment: @Shog9 I was referring specifically to the row highlighting for questions in your favorite tags, which Wayback Machine naturally can't capture. And yes, for me at least, it is an *enormous* change. On my color-calibrated monitor, I can make out the difference. On my rather lower quality, non-calibrated monitor, it's *hard*. And judging by some of the threads here on meta I'm hardly the only one feeling that way.

Comment: The syntax highlighting change was [a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283814/new-syntax-highlighting-just-got-me-color-blind/283842#283842), @Mathias - a pretty bad one, but we didn't catch it on meta because... well, there's not a whole lot of code highlighting here normally. It's fixed, big thanks to Marco for reporting it. There are other bugs, report 'em and we'll fix 'em.

Comment: I can see how that'd be jarring, @Chris - I personally don't use favorite tags *at all* because I've *always* hated the highlighting, so I imagine if you'd gotten used to it then changing it would make it annoying all over again. If you feel strongly, post or [support a request to change it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update/283819#283819).

Comment: Big pile of fixes / changes rolled out earlier today, @Richard; another is scheduled for later on. Which is why I'm trying to thank and encourage everyone taking time to highlight specific flaws - the faster we get this stuff fixed, the less painful it is for everyone. But hey, if you need to get the angst out first before you can do that, hop into [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) & get catharsis!

Comment: @Shog9 I didn't even notice the change. But: if it's so minor, then it can hardly be fixing "technical design debt", can it? (Referring to the design itself, and not the code behind it)

Comment: Quite a lot changed behind the scenes. The trick is to avoid making visible changes until they're wanted; that was... *mostly* successful.

Comment: I've been through thins kind of thing myself on a much bigger scale - at some point I decided that the code was just completely FUBAR and created a whole new website that just used the same premise but everything changed. So I know what it's like, and I know what kind of expectations users have from both sides of the story. And I know what kind of pain working with hacked-together code can be, but it's things like that that give a site *character*, and I feel like SO has lost of a lot of its character with this change...

Comment: @Shog9 The favorites highlighting matter isn't just about being used to something else. The contrast is _objectively bad_. Enter the RGB values (255, 245, 222) and (48, 167, 252) into this [contrast calculator](http://tinyurl.com/pen8ec6) and you will see that it fails on both brightness and hue. I really don't understand the styling decisions in the redesign. With liberal amounts of light pink, electric blue, and Helvetica Neue, if feels more like a birth announcement for a baby girl than a professional site for programming questions.

Comment: And the bizarre blue coloring seen in the questions list and on buttons in SO is not present here on Meta, so naturally nobody took issue with those during the beta. They couldn't have. And surprise, surprise, with the dark gray fonts being used here, highlighted favorites on the Meta questions list pass the contrast tests.

Comment: @JLRishe Don't argue about that in the comments. If you are concerned about the contrast open a meta question _specifically about that_ and reference evidence from the contrast calculator.  There have been a dozen of these _"zomg they changed everything and I hate it!!!!!"_  posts and they are not helpful.  _Individual issues_ like the contrast to that can be addressed on an _individual basis_ are helpful. Otherwise everyone's just complaining their cheese was moved. (It wasn't - it just got new plastic wrap over it)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski But... but... I wanna *eat* my cheese... :c -- I kid, of course, but my main concern in posting this on Meta was that too much was changed, *apparently* without proper testing. I was wrong about there being no testing at all, but the mass of bug reports show that *proper* testing may not have been done sufficiently, and proposed that the big change be reverted until it was properly fixed.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski [Done.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283937/contrast-on-highlighted-favorites-is-too-low)

Comment: @JLRishe Cool, and +1.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The team is being really aggressive about fixing design bugs as they're reported, which is great.

Comment: A note on the "redesign != refactor" argument...the design team *did* refactor the shared CSS file, which is part of the SO design update. They eliminated something like 4,000 lines of code - which makes it much easier to find and fix bugs when they're reported. What you see on the site is only the output of the design project; that doesn't mean there isn't a ton of stuff happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Is it just me, or did things get crisper over the last day or two?